# A problem on the number of distinct $1$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ is

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a 3-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb{Z}_3$ of elements . The number of distinct $1$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ is

$1. 13$
$2. 26$
$3. 9$
$4.15$

---

My thoughts:-

The subspaces of $1$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}^3$ are only the straight lines.
but I could not count it to $13$ as $13$ is the given answer.
I get the following equations.
$x=0$ , $y=0$ ,$z=0$. $\to$ $3$ subspaces
$x+ay=0$ $a=1,2$ $\to$ $2$ subspaces
$ax+y=0$ $a=2$ $\to$ $1$ subspace
 similar case for $y & z $ and $x & z$. so total is 12 and I missed $1$
somebody help me please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take any non-zero vector $(a,b,c)$. This generates a $1$-dimensional space. Two vectors generate the same space if and only if one is $k$ times the other, where $k$ is a non-zero constant.

In our case, there are $2$ non-zero constants, giving a count of $(3^3-1)/2$.

Exactly the same idea works in dimensions higher than $3$, and any finite field.

**Remark:** Alternately, we can reword the solution by talking about straight lines through the origin. If we want to break into cases, without loss of generality we may assume that $a=0$ or $a=1$. (If $a=2$ then we can multiply through by $2$ to get the same line.)

There are $3^2$ possibilities with $a=1$. For $a=0$, we can have $b=0$ (and then $1$ possibility for $c$) or $b=1$ (and then $3$ possibilities for $c$).

However, the approach given in the main answer is more efficient, since it takes full advantage of symmetry.

Comment: thanks. will you kindly give me the general formula

Comment: Let $F$ be a finite field with $m$ elements. (We know $m$ is a prime power, but won't need that.) Let $V$ be a $k$-dimensional vector space over $F$. Then the number of $1$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ is $\frac{m^k-1}{m-1}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas sir, could you give approach and general formula for, finding number of $k$ dimensional subspaces of $n$ dimensional vector space $V$?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Let $F$ be a finite field with $p$ elements and $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space. Then the number of $k$ dimensional subspace of $V$ is $\frac{(p^n -1)(p^n - p)...(p^n - p^{k-1})}{(p^k - 1)(p^k - p)...(p^k - p^{k-1})}$